# SwiftUI loading indicator placeholder hiding my list rows

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When my loading indicator placeholder `LoadingPlaceholderView` comes to view, it hides the whole list until it disappears. I want the list to be always visible during the `LoadingPlaceholderView` is in view. The `LoadingPlaceholderView` is in the correct position right now.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP2tz.png)

```
var body: some View {
            VStack {
                List {
                    if viewModel.isLoading {
                        // Loading indicator view
                        LoadingPlaceholderView()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    } else {

                        ForEach(viewModel.posts) { post in
                            HStack(alignment: .top) {

                                displayImageView(for: post)
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)

                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                                    HStack {
                                        profilePictureView(for: post)
                                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)

                                        Text(post.username)
                                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                                    }

                                    Text(post.caption)
                                        .font(.system(size: 10))
                                        .lineLimit(6)
                                        .truncationMode(.tail)
                                }
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.selectedPost = post
                                self.isSheetPresented = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.checkClipboardAndUpdateContent()
                    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                        forName: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
                        object: nil,
                        queue: .main
                    ) { [weak viewModel] _ in
                        viewModel?.checkClipboardAndUpdateContent()
                    }
                }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
                MediaPreviewSheet(post: $selectedPost)
                    .presentationBackground(.ultraThinMaterial)
                    .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
                    .presentationCornerRadius(20)
                
            }
            .onAppear {
             viewModel.isLoading = true
             }
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to fix it? I tried moving it around the stack but can't seem to place it properly.

Comment: Use an overlay instead of an if else

Comment: tried using overlay, but I prefer the loading indicator to display as a list row as it gets replaced with data when its completed, looks more like a part of the list @loremipsum

Comment: The just get rid of the else

Comment: oh cool that was it haha, thank you,. I can't believe that was all I needed to do. @loremipsum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your code is setup to show the `LoadingPlaceholderView` or the `ForEach`.

To show the `LoadingPlaceholderView` and the `ForEach` just remove the `else`.

The only thing that will be conditional is the `LoadingPlaceholderView`.

Comment: I thought that did it, which almost did. I removed the `else` and it works showing the list while its in view, the list is visible during the animation, but then when the animation placeholder disappears, the list disappears with it too. It's like the issue is opposite now.

Comment: Don’t include the ForEach in the if. Just remove the else and the {} for the else. Don’t move anything else. @xyz it sounds like you put the ForEach in the if.

Comment: That was it, now its perfect, thanks again! accepted your answer